# I already solved the problem. I just want to have some indepth explanation

Tags: python, replace

**The problem is**

```
onput = '2x**4 - 2x**3 - x**2 + 3x - 4'   #some random 5-term polynomial
factors = [1, -1, 2, -2, 5]
for i in range(len(factors)):
   subtitute = '({})'.format(factors[i])
   onput = onput.replace('x', subtitute)  #replaces 'x'
   print(onput)
```

Apparently that prints:

```
>>> 2(1)**4 - 2(1)**3 - (1)**2 + 3(1) - 4
>>> 2(1)**4 - 2(1)**3 - (1)**2 + 3(1) - 4
>>> 2(1)**4 - 2(1)**3 - (1)**2 + 3(1) - 4
>>> 2(1)**4 - 2(1)**3 - (1)**2 + 3(1) - 4
>>> 2(1)**4 - 2(1)**3 - (1)**2 + 3(1) - 4
```

Instead of:

```
>>> 2(1)**4 - 2(1)**3 - (1)**2 + 3(1) - 4
>>> 2(-1)**4 - 2(-1)**3 - (-1)**2 + 3(-1) - 4
>>> 2(2)**4 - 2(2)**3 - (2)**2 + 3(2) - 4
>>> 2(-2)**4 - 2(-2)**3 - (-2)**2 + 3(-2) - 4
>>> 2(5)**4 - 2(5)**3 - (5)**2 + 3(5) - 4
```

**So my solution is:**

```
onput = '2x**4 - 2x**3 - x**2 + 3x - 4'
factors = [1, -1, 2, -2, 5]
for i in range(len(factors)):
    subtitute = '({})'.format(factors[i])
    xonput = onput.replace('x', subtitute)
    print(xonput)
```

which successfully printed my intended result. But the thing is I don't quite understand why using the same list to call the same list would make this bug that keeps the first item of the factor-list as the  per replacement instead of replacing it by the every item of the list per replacement.

Comment: In my opinion you should move your solution to answers space.

Comment: - because in post it's looks bad.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that, in the first loop, `onput` is modified to replace all the `x` placeholder, so, on the next iteration, there are no more `x` to replace in `onput`.

By using a different variable (`xonput`), this overriding of the template string is avoided.